# Distinct result with row_id for limit query

Tags: postgresql, subquery, limits, offset-fetch

There are 2 tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE sample1 (
  id int,
  name varchar,
  score int,
  mode int
)

CREATE TABLE sample2 (
  id int,
  mode int
  ...
)
```

I need to select distinct `name` with `MIN(score)` and `ROW_NUMBER()`. Must sort by `ROW_NUMBER() ASC`. The `mode` must exist in table `sample2` for a row from `sample1`, so there is `INNER JOIN`.

`ROW_NUMBER()` is needed for sequential LIMIT queries so I can select data in batches. I don't care about consistency of that LIMIT+ROW_NUMBER() trick.

My query:

```sql
WITH sample1 AS (
    WITH sample1 AS (
        SELECT a.name, MIN(a.score) s
        FROM sample1 a
            JOIN sample2 USING (mode)
            GROUP BY a.name
    )
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s ASC) AS n
    FROM sample1
) SELECT * FROM sample1 WHERE n > $1 LIMIT $2
```

I am concerned about efficiency of that select, in fact it's 3 level deep subquery. Perhaps there are less ugly and more efficient ways to achieve same result?

The number of rows in this table will be approximately 1,000,000 and distinct set is expected to be 100,000. Queries are frequent, actually it's a hot table for select, only score column will be updated in batches of the same size as limit select.

Comment: I would give a chance to replace that `JOIN` with an `EXISTS` or a `mode in` condition. The result may depend on actual data and postgres version too. I dont get whats the point of using distinct together with the group by.

Comment: Yes, I will remove distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would seem like you do not need any CTE, subquery or even `JOIN` at all. Just an [`EXISTS`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS) semi-join and an additional [`OFFSET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-LIMIT):

```
SELECT name
     , MIN(score) AS s
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(score)) AS n  -- still needed?
FROM   sample1 a
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT FROM sample2 s2 WHERE s2.mode = a.mode)
GROUP  BY name
ORDER  BY s
OFFSET $1
LIMIT  $2;
```

A large `OFFSET` is always costly, as all the leading, discarded rows have to be considered in the ordering first.

If it's a read-only table, you could add a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html) with an index on the row number and query with `SELECT * FROM mv WHERE n > $1 AND n <= $1 + $2`.
Would help most for big `$1` and small `$2`.